# Could somebody explain this: thing variable= new thing();?

Tags: java

I am really new to Java and I'm trying to learn it. Therefore, I watched tutorials and stuff and somewhere it said:

```
Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
```

but as I put this in my code it doesn't work. I know that's a way to create new classes, but that didn't happen in the tutorial.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html Could somebody please explain it to me?

Code:

```
public class Test1 {
    int keybordcolor=1;
    int keybordshape=2;
    int keyboardbuttons=37;

    void changekeyboardcolor(int newvalue) {
        keybordcolor=newvalue;
    }
    void changekeybordshape(int newvalue) {
        keybordshape=newvalue;
    }
    void changekeybordbuttons(int adition) {
        keyboardbuttons= keyboardbuttons+adition;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Keyboard Skillerpro = new Keyboard();
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
    }
}
```

The error is "Cant be resolved to a type"

Comment: Please elaborate "it didnt work". Didnt work how? What was the error message? Can you provide the whole code?

Comment: `Bicycle` is class You have to create the class or refer the class from same package or import it via library

Comment: Have you defined a `Bicycle` class in your project? If you have, then are you sure this class has a proper constructor? If not, please **READ** all the explanation in the link you've posted in the question related to the official Java tutorial about classes.

Comment: I know that thats a way to craete classes, but they didnt do it in the tutorial ^^

Comment: DId you actually write a class called `Bicycle` or `Keyboard`, with a constructor, getters, and setters?

Comment: So i Need to make a class...ok i think im getting it...

Comment: @tankman175 You need to import Keyboard class and Bicycle class. I tried to answer your question based on your previous version of the question. Looking at your edited question, I want to tell you: Start from very basics. You are trying to create Keyboard and Bicycle object but don't have them imported in your class. You need to understand what class is and what variables are...start from basics. I have included links in my answer for that.

Comment: ok, so i created a class called Keyboard and added "skillerpro.changekeyboardcolor(2);" to my code before the last curved bracket and it says "Syntax error on Token delete Token (2)"and "syntax error on token, misplaced constructs".

Comment: @user3320018 i know what a variable is, im not thaat new^^ and i do think to know what a class is. But more important, where are the links in your answer?:)

Comment: oh ok that link, sorry

Comment: @tankman175 what is skillerpro.changekeyboardcolor(2)? is this something you have implemented in Keyboard class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bicyle bike1 = new Bicycle() is correct and would work as long as you
>   have Bicycle.java class and you have JDK in classpath on your machine.

`Bicycle` as you have mentioned is a java class and with that line, you are attempting to create an object (an instance with reference name: `bike1`) of the class. In this particular class (Bicycle) constructor arguments are not required. 
Refer to the basics from Oracle Java Docs on this [site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), there is explanation of how to create objects and how to use them, this particular link also has instruction on creating objects with constructor arguments.

The best way is to learn the basics from the Oracle/Java tutorial pages. Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will read through the Documentation.